# ListView dynamic anchoring

Tags: qt, qml

Let us suppose I have a card made using `Rectangle` and I want to show buttons on top of it when clicked. I'm calling `showMenu()` function to do that and for buttons I'm using an `ListView` with dynamic `ListModel`. The problem with such is that the button gets added bellow the `Rectangle` instead of the top of it. The anchor is not updating after appending an item to the model. Here is my code

```
Item {
    width: 120
    height: 120
    Rectangle {
        id: card
        width: 50
        height: 100
        color: "pink"
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        Item {
            id: rec
            width: 50
            anchors.bottom: parent.top    // This anchor is not updating after appending an item to the list.

            ListModel {
                id: menuListModel
            }

            Component {
                id: delegate
                Rectangle {
                    width: 120
                    height: 20
                    color: "blue"
                    Text {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: commandText
                    }
                }
            }

            ListView {
                anchors.fill: parent
                model:menuListModel
                delegate: delegate
                interactive: false
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: menuListModel.append({"commandText" : "Normal Summon"});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code that runs?

Comment: updated the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more or less a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111982/qml-form-layout-gridlayout-troubles). The `Item` needs a `height`. As mentioned in the answer to that question, you can add debug statements to the code when things like this happen. In this situation, you can also add a `Rectangle` as a child of the `Item` and make sure that it's visible:

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "transparent"
    border.color: "darkorange"
}
```

If it's not visible, you know that the problem lies with that (parent) item.

Comment: Adding height would solve the current example, but in my code the height is dynamic, so should I keep on updating the height each time an object is appended to the model ? Or is there any way the height of the `ListView` is updated from the top of it instead from the bottom ?

Comment: So the height of the item depends on the height of the `ListView`?

Comment: Yes height of the `Item` depends on the height of the `ListView`.

Comment: And the height of the `ListView` depends on the height of the `Item`. :p So, you need to give the `Item` a `height`.

Comment: If I add `rec.height += 10;` in `onClicked` before appending object the model, it's working correctly. But shouldn't the height be updated automatically.